# How can we write a Joi schema for different request types?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, validation, joi

I've been trying to create a schema. It represents my object, which is like `{name:"Joe Doe", id:"1234567890"}` But on the first request which is for creating new one; it should not have an id parameter in the object. Otherwise it might be meaning an update to consumer...

Would you have any idea about the best way to implement it?

**What I need as a joi schema**;

```
joi.object().keys({
    id: joi.string().forbidden() or required(),
    name: joi.string(),
    ...
```

**Sample requests;**

Create:

**POST** Request... 
'api/v1/item/'

Object : `{name:"Joe Doe"}`

Update:

**PUT** Request... 
'api/v1/item/'

Object : `{id:"1234567890", name:"Joe Doe"}`

Comment: can you add request and payload example with the question please?

Comment: @AshishModi I've added them.

Comment: added the answer. hope it helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the project, we still use 14.3.1 version of joi.
I could solve my problem with creating a base joi object and extending it like;

```
const base = joi.object().keys({name: joi.string()});
const put = base.keys({
    id: joi.string().required(),
});
const post = base.keys({
    id: joi.string().forbidden(),
});
```

Even it looks cleaner to read. I leave that here for if someone needs something similar.

Comment: Hi, I need to do same , can you please share complete example ?

Answer (score 6):

You can use Joi's context option while calling validate method. something like

```
var Joi = require("@hapi/joi");

const schema = Joi.when(Joi.ref("$method"), {
          "is": "put",
          "then": Joi.object().keys({
            "id": Joi.string().required(),
            "name": Joi.string()
          }),
          "otherwise": Joi.object().keys({
            "id": Joi.string().forbidden(),
            "name": Joi.string()
          })
        });

function validate() {
    const result = schema.validate({"id": "123", "name": "myname"}, {"context": {"method": "put"}});
    console.log(result);
}

validate();
```

if you pass method as put, it will use put schema else post schema.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same use case on my app, what I've done is adding a flag on the Joi context

```js
const conditionalIdValue = Joi.any().when('$isEditForm', {
  is: Joi.boolean()
    .valid(true)
    .required(),
  then: Joi.string()
    .required(),
  otherwise: Joi.forbidden(),
});

const schema = joi.object().keys({
  id: conditionalIdValue,
  name: joi.string(),
  ...
});
```

where I'm calling `Joi.validate` I have an access to the request it self, so you can attach `isEditForm` with the proper value on the context.

```js
// validation middleware

export const validationMiddleWare = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    req.body = await Joi.validate(req.body, schema, {
      context: { isEditForm: req.method === 'POST' },
    });
    return next();
  } catch (e) {
    // reject the request
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const Joi = require("joi");

const schema = Joi.object().keys({
   //General attributes that will be required in all put/post request
  noOfCopies: Joi.number().required(),
});

const put = schema.keys({
    customerId: Joi.string().required().forbidden(),
    movieId: Joi.string().required().forbidden(),
});

const post = schema.keys({
  customerId: Joi.string().required(),
  movieId: Joi.string().required(),
});

function validator(payload,method) {
  
  const validationMethod = (method === "POST" ) ? post : put ;
  const { error } = validationMethod.validate(payload);

  return error;
}

module.exports = validator;


//In Your Controller
validator(req.body,req.method)
```